# Mapping an Aliased Virtual Directory(IIS) to chrome workspace

Tags: google-chrome, iis, google-chrome-devtools, workspace

Web application has a physical path MyWebApp and VirtualDirectory Alias set to MyWeb.

How to configure MyWebApp folder to MyWeb DevTools Workspaces mapping on chrome. 
Currently they show up as two different workspaces(one from server, one local due to difference in name).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Settings panel, under Workspace you have the option to add the workspace directory. Once you have done that, you can set up the specific mappings. The 'URL prefix' would be the IIS virtual directory, the 'Folder path' is the physical path it maps to.

[image: Workspaces]